# How to implement an association class with a bidirectional many-to-many relationsship?

Tags: c#, uml, associations, implementation

I have an association class named `Role`, like this:

[image]

I haven't really worked with association classes before, so I have to ask: Is this the correct use of it?
The idea is that each person has a specific role in each of the groups, while each group also knows the people they're associated with.

Even though I understand the principle, I have no clue how to actually implement it.

Comment: Why don't you ask a specific question instead of an open ended one.

Comment: Isn't StackOverflow about asking questions that are clear and are general enough to be useful to other people in the future? If you agree with that, then I don't understand what you mean. What exactly should be more specific about this question?

Comment: This question is in the realm of software architecture.  The answer is subjective.  I recommend removing "which one is the best".  The latter is a comparison of pro's and con's.  This is a good fit for Programmers SE.  Voting to close as migration to PSE appears to have been removed.

Comment: I don't understand. Why is it subjective? Which factors makes this subjective? I'm not talking about coding style here. As far as I'm aware, I'm talking about how to implement a very simple association design. Is there something I don't understand here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the straight-forward implementation is to have the association class (I'd name it `GroupMembership` for clarity) contain

- a reference to a Person
- a reference to a Group
- additional data members describing the nature of the group membership (like your `isAdmin`, or a reference to another object describing the nature of the membership)

The `Person` class contains a list of references to `GroupMembership` objects, describing to which groups the person belongs to.

The `Group` class also contains a list of references to `GroupMembership` objects, giving you information about the members of the group.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, this was what I was looking for. What about when you want to associate a `Person` and a `Group`, do you just include the opposite information in the association method, like if the user had a method: `public void AddGroup(GroupMembership gm, Group g)` and then handle the association bidirectionally in that method, or is it possible to do this without including either the `GroupMembership` or the `Group`? Or is this where the subjective matter comes in?

Comment: I think it depends on personal preference and the rest of your program whether you want the logic to create such an association inside the Person, the Group, or outside (e.g. a static method in the GroupMembership class).